# (Non-remote) Chome Dev Tools ("Inspect element") equivalent on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, html, web-inspector

Is there any way to have the Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug or something similar on Android **without using another computer**?

I'd like to use my Android Tablet + Bluetooth keyboard as a notebook replacement, and inspecting and debugging HTML/CSS/JavaScript is the only major feature I'm missing.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm in the exactly same boat as you. The best I've achieved so far is using a Firebug Lite bookmarklet.

Add the following code as a bookmark:

```
javascript:(function(F,i,r,e,b,u,g,L,I,T,E){if(F.getElementById(b))return;E=F[i+'NS']&&F.documentElement.namespaceURI;E=E?F[i+'NS'](E,'script'):F[i]('script');E[r]('id',b);E[r]('src',I+g+T);E[r](b,u);(F[e]('head')[0]||F[e]('body')[0]).appendChild(E);E=new%20Image;E[r]('src',I+L);})(document,'createElement','setAttribute','getElementsByTagName','FirebugLite','4','firebug-lite.js','releases/lite/latest/skin/xp/sprite.png','https://getfirebug.com/','#startOpened');
```

It's far from perfect, but the best I've found.